# Nested display in django admin (multipe foreign keys)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Let's say I have 3 models, a company, its divisions, and the divisions' employees. Divisions have a foreign key to companies and employees have a foreign key to divisions. Is there a way to make it work so that the list display in the django admin for companies does something like:

```
General Electric
    Finance
            Tom Brown
            Bill Black
            John Green
    Technology
            Deer Rabbit
    Marketing
Target
    ...
```

Comment: How about this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151603/can-i-use-the-djangos-default-admin-app-for-this-model/11151858#11151858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes totally, to be able to do that you will have to customize your admin views, here are the docs: http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter17/

There is very similar example in the docs so it should be easy to follow :)

Comment: Where is the similar example if you dont mind pointing me to it?

Comment: sure, if you see the fire 17-2 it shows some header fields with subclasses, in you case you would only need to change those headers to be urls too. It is around the end of the page

Comment: Thanks. That helps but is not exactly what Im looking for. I dont want to modify the existing template, just admin.py. I feel like this should be possible..

Comment: you can extend the template, no need to build it from scratch, I don't think there is a cleaner way to do this, but if you found another I would love to know. bests of luck!